# Hello World in Webratio

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm completely new to Webratio and trying to get hello world working.

I've just created a new Hello World Project

[image: Hello World]

Here's what it looks like

[image: Project]

I've created a debug configuration

[image: debug]

But when I hit debug I get an error message

[image: error]

I'm not sure what this error means

> Deployment information not found for project HelloWorld: regenerate
>   the project and retry.

And Google doesn't seem to know this message either.

So then I thought, maybe Webratio projects are not mean to be built, maybe I am supposed to do something else.

I tried the Generate and Run on cloud button.

[image: cloud]

but this did not appear to produce any results.

I also tried hitting the deploy button.

There were two types of deployments available to me, 
1. Webratio
2. OpenShift

Using a Webratio Deployment I get an error message

> Unrecognized cloud account for launch configuration 'HelloWorld -
>   WebRatio Cloud'

I think this is because I don't have an account with webratio.

Using the openshift deployment seems to work without errors, but I can't find any output.

I get a message in the console which reads

> [30 Sep 2015 09:39:33,021] Output Folder: C:\WebRatio\WebRatio
>   Community Platform 7.2.9.x64bit\WebRatio\deploy [30 Sep 2015
>   09:39:33,062] Deployment Time 0 secs

But then that folder is empty

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

I Just found this on the Webratio website

> The Community Cloud Edition allows you to build and test, for free,
>   any applications that you are modeling, giving you access to a
>   temporary cloud space. This temporary space is cleared every two
>   hours.

And also this

> WebRatio Platform is among the very few cloud platforms in the world
>   that does not obscure the code produced and allows you to use it as
>   you like. But this capability is only available for our Enterprise
>   edition customers

I probably cant get the source code since I have not yet bought an account. But I should still be able to test hello world.

**EDIT**

I just checked for updates to Webratio/eclipse

Help->Install New Software ...

And now when I try to deploy to the cloud I can get an actual error message!

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   com.webratio.ide.deploy.ui.generator.actions.GenerateAndRunOnCloudAction$ActionRunnable.run(GenerateAndRunOnCloudAction.java:239)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Unable to retrieve
>   the free cloud account    at
>   com.webratio.ide.deploy.ui.generator.actions.GenerateAndRunOnCloudAction$ActionRunnable.run(GenerateAndRunOnCloudAction.java:209)
>     ... 1 more

Looks like I need to figure out how to get a free cloud account

Comment: I've installed apache tomcat

Comment: Here's the tutorial I'm trying to replicate 
https://my.webratio.com/learn/learningobject/create-a-hello-world-application?link=oln72ae.redirect&history=h1&nav=27

Comment: This article lists a bunch of cloud services which are not available to me http://my.webratio.com/learn/learningobject/Deployment-Configurations-and-Cloud-Deploy#toc8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebRatio Community Edition lets you generate and run your project on the cloud.
This means that you cannot get the output in the deploy folder but you can navigate your application from the WebRatio Cloud Free Space that is associated to your account.

You do not need to buy anything.

When you press the Generate and Run on Cloud, at the end of the process your browser should open and show you the home page of your Web application.

If this is not happening, you can still access your WebRatio Cloud Free Account going on http://www.webratio.com/cloud
This is the dashboard from which you can manage the account and access the application. More information about the WebRatio Cloud Dashboard are available [here](https://my.webratio.com/learn/learningobject/webratio-cloud-dashboard-user-guide-v-72).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot solve your web ratio problem as I have never used it but you can do web development in any other editor ex(Eclipse, Dreamweaver, Sublime, ...) and use a local websever to test code as that looks like thats what you are trying to do. Try to launch your web app from XAMPP https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html and see if your hello world project will launch from there. If this works you can use webratio to code and test with XAMPP and then you know the problem exists with running a enternal server through webratio. If your project wont run through XAMPP then you know you have a problem within Model.wr. It would be helpful to see the code for the page in which you are trying to launch.

Comment: My understanding of webratio is that it is supposed to generate code from `Model.wr`. So I don't  think I have even generated any code yet.

Comment: That could definitely be the problem. I am not sure to your level of expertise or the type of server you are trying to run but to simply check if thats the problem add a html file to the index of your project folder where Model.wr is.

Comment: sample code for a defualt html page that when you launch your project should be displayed as the homepage of the site if you name the file index.html

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"

        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">



<html lang="en">



<head>



 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

 <title>Title Goes Here</title>



</head>



<body>

<p>This is my web page</p>



</body>



</html>

Comment: I've added that `index.html` to the folder with `Model.wr`. But I think the problem is that no html is being generated. I still get all the same error messages.

Comment: I cannot solve the specific issue inside webratio but your problem lies within the files are not being served to the web. have you tried serving the project off a web server or a internal server like XAMPP. If it runs elsewhere    just code in the app and use another app to launch and test.

Comment: hmm ... I don't think its possible for me to get the source code until I buy it.

Comment: coding is free. find a alternative program. Notepad ++ or sublime trial. To achieve what you want you don't need to pay just try a alternative.